# How to express an interval in a cost function

Tags: optimization, interval-arithmetic

I'm trying to best express a cost function and I'm unclear on how to properly add an interval-based constraint. The cost function is used to minimize a cubic function.

My cost function has 3 components:

- Quadratic $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N{(\hat{y}-y})^2$
- L2 Regularization $\lambda\sum_{i=2}^kw_i^2$
- Interval-based constraint $\sigma_{f(x)}, x\epsilon(80,\infty)$

Is the following a clear way to express this? I'm concerned that the notation is not clear.

$min \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N{(\hat{y}-y})^2 + \lambda\sum_{i=2}^kw_i^2 + \sigma_{f(x)}, x\epsilon(80,\infty)$

Comment: What is $f(x)$?  What does $\sigma_{f(x)}$ mean?

Comment: f(x) is the cubic function that I am trying to optimize. σf(x) is the standard deviation of the values evaluated above 80. If I can edit my question, let's set the upper bound to 100. So the new interval is (80,100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed not clear (to me). This is what I think you mean.

Call your three terms $A$, $B$ and $C$. Then
$$
\text{cost}(x) = \min\begin{cases}
A + B \quad\quad\quad \text{ if } x  \le 80 \\
A+B+C  \quad \text{ if } x > 80
\end{cases}
$$

For clarity, I would in fact define $A$, $B$ and $C$ first rather than inlining them in the `\cases` statement.